# Seeking explanation for Auto-Casting

Tags: java, exception

So I just spent around an hour trying to unveil and resolve a very strange bug, one that I have never seen before.

**I am more or less asking for potential causes of this seeming random cast from enum to String rather than "please fix my code for me"**.

The gist of the problem is as follows:

I have an interface, call it `IFoo`, within this interface, it has a static enum, called `Bar`:

```
public interface IFoo {
  static enum Bar{
    A,
    B,
    C,
  }

  Bar doGetBar();
}
```

I of course have a `Foo` class that implements `IFoo`.

```
public class Foo implements IFoo{
  public Bar getBar(){
    return Bar.A; // for example
  }
}
```

Somewhere else, I have an object array called

```
Object[] result;
```

And a helper method that returns an array of `Object`s, holding results from the `getBar()`method, call it

```
public Object[] getBars()
```

Now, when I do

```
result = getBars();
```

`result` magically holds `String`s instead of `Bar`s, the values of the strings are the implementation class of the outer class (not really an outer class, more of a wrapper class?)  of `Bar`, i.e. "Foo".

Could someone possibly explain to me how this is possible?

Some leads: 
1. results were holding strings before the assignment.
2. the static enum inside IFoo is questionable, it was non-static, but it caused `ClassCastException`s when I tried to cast it to IFoo.Bar from Foo.Bar (or something along these lines).

Comment: You need to post an actual working piece of code that we can look at

Comment: If I can't do that, should I close the thread?

Comment: why would that be impossible?

Comment: I'm not asking you to reproduce the entire codebase :-) Just write a small program like the above demonstrating the bug and only the bug. After all, you seem to be asking "there's a bug in some code what I wrote but can't show you". How is anyone supposed to help with that?

Comment: It won't be possible to diagnose the problem by looking at completely different (and inconsisten) code that you *think* contains the essence of what causes this strange behaviour in your actual code. Either post the actual code, or try to reproduce the problem in a minimal example - you may well discover the underlying problem while constructing that example.

Comment: Then tailor your code sample such a way to protect the innocent.

Comment: I'm more or less asking for possible causes of CCE instead of "what's wrong with my code".

Comment: @Michael - I disagree. It's usually trying to isolate what you *think is the issue* that reveals the true culprit!

Comment: Possible causes of a CCE? There's only one. You have an instance of class B - you are trying to cast it to a class to which it is not assignable

Comment: @oxbow_lakes I re-disagree. What you think is the issue very often isn't. Of course that will show when the problem disappears in the process and may therefore lead you towards understanding - but only in working code, not in framentes of pseudo-code that won't even compile.

Comment: Yes - I agree about the pseudo-code: I want a working example of the bug in a short program. Of course, the OP won't be able to reproduce it because what they think is happening is not happening. So then they add code to get more like their real system. At some point the bug will appear and they will have their cause.

Comment: Sorry!!!  I was working with something else that was giving me ClassCastException, but this wasn't it.  This is the magical auto-casting issue which eventually leads to my CCE.

I've edited my title.

Comment: You really should post more code.

Comment: You've edited the title but the body of the question is unchanged.

Comment: This needs to get changed, wtf r u doing.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes.  Rare case of drama on SO, what gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what "magic" is contained within the `getBars()` method, and without more information, It's not possible to produce a sample implementation to verify this behaviour. Specifically, it's not clear what "a helper method that returns an array of Objects, holding results from the getBar() method" means.

If you can, isolate the smallest test case containing the behaviour, as suggested. oxbow_lakes' suggestion is also good; bring a simple test as close to the real behaviour as possible.

If you really can't produce a simplified scenario to show us, then our ability to help you is going to be severely curtailed, since that `getBar()` method is where the `Object[]` is populated. In that case, if you can't work it out, then I suggest you may have to ask a more knowledgeable colleague for a bit of help - could be a second set of eyes will spot it.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Object[]` has got `String`s in it because *you put them there*. If you post a small example piece of code demonstrating clearly that you put `Bar`s in but get `String`s out I will be very surprised.

The method for resolving bugs like this is to start from the beginning, making a simple *working* example (which will likely not display the bug). Then keep adding code to make it more like your real-world application until the bug rears its head. Then you'll be able to identify your most recent change as the source of the bug.

Comment: Well, I looked through the debugger, and evaluated the output of the right hand side directly after the assignment.  One was holding String objects, and one was holding enums.

Comment: There are a few options. 1) you have made a mistake about what you thought you saw in the debugger. 2) you have made a mistake about what code you thought you were executing in the debug step. 3) There is a fundamental issue with the JVM. On your machine. And no-one elses. Take my advice - you need to slowly and methodically recereate your problem from scratch. I know it's a pain. But it **will work**

Answer (score 2):

Use collections and generics for type safety instead.

**Edit** As now the question changed to a conceptional level, I'll use my telesense to figure out the cause.

It seems you are reusing an Object[] array on line 252 for completely different purposes. The compiler accepts

```
Object[] objs = Bar.values();
//...
objs = "A B C".split("\\s+");
//...
return objs;
```

this kind of code because arrays in Java are covariant (e.g. String[] is subclass of Object[]). Reusing a base class object array this way is troublesome.

Comment: First question: "Why can't I assign an `ArrayList<String>` to `List<Object>`?"?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your `getBars()` method looks like this:

```
     public Object[] getBars() {
     return Bar.values();
 }
```

if you are wondering what you should be receiving from the 'Bar.values()' method, check out [the JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf).  In your case, `values()` would return type `FooI$Bar`.

It might be useful to post, not only the code that you have put together that throws the exception, but the ClassCastException as well.